# Помогите пожалуйста срочно надо

Tags: падежи

Просклоняйте дробь 11/34 и 37/71

Comment: Предложите свой вариант склонения, а мы исправим ошибки

Comment: И.п одиннадцать тридцать четвёртых Р.п одиннадцати тридцать четвёртых Д.п одиннадцати тридцать четвёртым В.п одиннадцать тридцать четвёртых Т.п одиннадцатью тридцать четвертыми П.п об одиннадцати тридцать четвёртых                                                       И.п тридцать семь семьдесят первых Р.п тридцати семи семьдесят первых Д.п тридцати семи семьдесят первым В.п тридцать сем семьдесят первых Т.п тридцатью семью семьдесят первыми П.п о тридцати семи семьдесят первых

Comment: Никита, сочу[в]ствую Вам.

Comment: Вы в каком смысле

Comment: @Никита Степанов, извините, что я влез в комментарий, который должен был заполнить @Галактион - уж не обижайтесь на него. Из Вашего ответа на предложение @виктор1799 следует, что Вы - тот человек, с которым легко общаться: работать, дружить, обсуждать проблему; Вы не подведёте товарища, не оставите его в беде (то-бишь: без ответа) и т. д. Ваш вопрос, вызванный репликой @Галактион,  подтверждает то, что я уже сказал. @Галактион у нас - весь в квадратной скобке, как буква "в" в его реплике: поди - разберись, что он хотел этим сказать. Мне интересно узнать, кому он будет отвечать: Вам или мне?

Answer (score 3):

Вы верно просклоняли: числитель-количественное числительное, от 5 до 20 и 30 склоняются как сущ.1 склонения, 37-сложное числит., меняются обе части ;знаменатель-порядковое, меняется только последнее слово.(Только  В.п тридцать семЬ семьдесят первых -Ь пропустили)